# java.interop.tools.diagnos error XA2006 in XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin

hi please help me to understand .in xamarin project in release mod this error happened.but in debug its ok.idont know what happend

```html
 `Severity Code Description Project Project Rank Path File Line Source Suppression State Tool
Error  Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException' (defined in assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') with scope 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Configuration.ConfigurationException
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args) in /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Diagnostic.cs:line 165
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() NetFileApp 2    Build  
`
```

Comment: There could be a lot of different reasons that its failing https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123556/linking-issue-android . What change did you make before it stopped working? What is the linker behavior set to? What is your target android framework?

Comment: Hi , you can have a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/) , and check whether miss something to do .